# How to append input value with ,(comma) when li click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have HTML like below,

```
<ul class="holder" style="width: 512px;">
    <li id="pt_5uZqW99dmlgmiuCTJiPHDC9T9o2sfz0I"
    rel="test1@gmail.com"
    class="bit-box">test1@gmail.com<a href="#" class="closebutton"></a>
    </li>
    <li id="pt_9O0pMJDhtNbRgU1vNM8He8Vh9zpJ1tcE" 
    rel="test2@gmail.com"
    class="bit-box">test2@gmail.com<a href="#" 
    class="closebutton"></a>
    </li>
    <li id="pt_U8JH5E9y5w4atm4CadEPvuu3wdh3WcBx" 
    rel="test3@gmail.com" 
    class="bit-box">test3@gmail.com<a href="#"
    class="closebutton"></a></li>
    <li id="Project_update_user_id_annoninput" 
     class="bit-input">
     <input type="text" autocomplete="off" size="0" class="maininput"></li>
    </ul>


<input id="removeuser" value="" />
```

I need to store the values of li's in hidden input box when I click that li's.
If I click first two li's i need to store the values like,

```
<input id="removeuser" value="test1@gmail.com,test2@gmail.com" />
```

That is i need to append input values every time when i click li's.

i used below one,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){                

       jQuery("a.closebutton").click(function(){

          jQuery("input#removeuser").val(jQuery.map(jQuery(this).parent().attr('rel')).join(","));

        });

    });
```

But it does not works.how can i do that?

Comment: clicking once on <a> adds item into hidden value, clicking second time removes it or no removal from value?

Comment: @Ivan Hušnjak no.every time it adds only with (,) seperator.

Comment: Something like [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/WpyUf/7/) ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ySV6F/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){                
   jQuery("a.closebutton").click(function(){
      jQuery("input#removeuser").val(jQuery("input#removeuser").val() + "," + jQuery(this).parent().attr('rel'));
      $(this).remove();
       return false;
    });
});​
```

Comment: now that OP has picked your answer, I would request you to handle the comma as that would make it complete! ;)

Comment: i guess he wanted it simple and fast, but you can suggest an edit to my post and add a second solution (but keep mine). and i will +1 your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This fiddle fixes your issue: http://jsfiddle.net/pratik136/zVmwg/

First change I did was move your text within the `<a />` tags. This allowed you to click on them as expected.

Next, I changed the `JS` to:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("a.closebutton").click(function(a) {
        var v = jQuery(this).parent().attr('rel');
        var t = jQuery("input#removeuser").val();
        if (t.indexOf(v) < 0) {
            if(t.length>0){
                t += ",";
            }
            jQuery("input#removeuser").val(t + v);
        }
    });
});​
```

I addded the additional check to ensure no duplicates are entered, and that a comma is appended only when necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var arr = [];
$(".closebutton").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var email = $(this).parent("li").attr("rel");
    if( $(this).hasClass("added") ) {
        arr= $.grep(arr, function(value) {
            return value != email;
       });
        $(this).removeClass("added");
    }
    else {
        arr.push( email );
        $(this).addClass("added");
    }
    $("input[id='removeuser']").val( arr.join(",") );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First I would suggest that instead of using `rel` attribute (which has a specific meaning in (X)HTML with certain tags) you use html safe `data-*` attributes

like this:

```
<li id="pt_5uZqW99dmlgmiuCTJiPHDC9T9o2sfz0I" data-email="mdineshkumarcs@gmail.com" 
class="bit-box">mdineshkumarcs@gmail.com<a href="#" class="closebutton"></a></li>
```

To access this attribute just use jQuery `$(elem).attr('data-email')`

Now the solution with no duplicates:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("a.closebutton").click(function(){
        var value = $(this).parent().attr('data-email');
        var values = $("input#removeuser").val().split(',');
        var is_in = false;
        // already in?
        $.each(values, function(i, e){
            if(e == value) {
                is_in = true; return false; // set and exit each
            }
        });
        if (!is_in) {
            values.push(value);
            $("input#removeuser").val(values.join(','));
        }

        return false;
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I've put the working code on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dpqa2/) so that you can see it in action.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){                

jQuery("a.closebutton").bind('click', function(){
    var data = $(this).parent().attr('rel');
    if($("#removeuser").val() == ""){        
        $("#removeuser").val(data);
    } else {
        $("#removeuser").val(", "+data);
    }
    $(this).parent().hide();
});

});​
```

Here I'm removing the `li` once clicked. You may I believe use the `.toggle()` function to enable users to remove a value from `#removeuser` as well.
Hope this helps!